# Embed YouTube video iframe is not working in iOS Webview with pagination

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, uiwebview, youtube-api

I'm using UIWebview with Pagination enabled(Left to Right Mode). I have a html content which has more than 3 pages of content(in iPhone 5) with image and video(iframe to embed youtube video) tags in between. My problem is youtube videos are not playing when the iframe tags are in other pages(except first page) but works fine when pagination is in Top to Bottom mode.

Ex: I have 3 pages of html content with one image and one youtube video in a webview with pagination in LeftToRightMode. Video is working fine if iframe is placed within first html page(I have only one html file, since webview paging is enabled html content is divided into 3 pages) but it doesn't respond/play when it is placed in second or third page. Whereas I'm able to play video in any page if webview paging mode is in TopToBottomMode(I have tried only LeftToRight and TopToBottom modes).

// setting Webview

```
-(void)loadHtmlContentsFromFile {

NSString *htmlContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
self.webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
self.webView.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
self.webView.gapBetweenPages = 0;
self.webView.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[self.webView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
[self.webView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContents baseURL:baseUrl];    
htmlContents = nil;
baseUrl = nil;
}
```

// HTML5 Content, iframe tag placed in 2nd page(as per webview pagination) is not working in UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight pagination mode

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>
    1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    <img alt="Lorem Ipsum" src="some_image.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; margin: 2px;" /></p>

    <p>
2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
    <p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px;">
    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="300" height="169" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" allowfullscreen frameborder="10">
    </iframe>
    </p>
<p>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiudaLorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</p>

    <p>
    3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So why is it? and how can I play youtube video in uiwebview with LeftToRightMode?!

Thanks.